# In app purchase through sim card for android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any functionality in Google's in-app purchase API that can charge a user's sim card? I would like to allow a user to make an in-app purchase with just a button click and without the hassle of entering a credit card number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood how In-App purchases (for Android) work. From the [In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) page:

> When you use Android Market's in-app billing service to sell an item,
>   Android Market handles all checkout details so your application never
>   has to directly process any financial transactions. Android Market
>   uses the same checkout service that is used for application purchases,
>   so your users experience a consistent and familiar purchase flow.

So what this means is that when the user makes an In-App purchase *within* your application, the *checkout* procedure is identical to if/when they purchase an app in the Android Market. Assuming they have a credit card registered with Android Market, it gets automatically charged and your users are good to go. If they don't have a credit card registered, they're prompted to add/register one when they initiate the purchase.

In either case, **it's all taken care of by Google**.

Comment: hi si Text2Pay legal service? That is what i am looking for. Does google has something similar?

Comment: @NoviceMe Briefly going through `Text2Pay`, I presume that in-app purchases work similarly - in that you (as the developer) do not have to worry about handling the financial transaction yourself, it's taken care of for you. Now having said that, I'm almost certain that it's against Android Market policy to use _other_ payment systems within your Android (Market) app - so my interpretation of that would be: _no, you cannot use Text2Pay for an app you publish in the Android Market_. Of course I'm not a lawyer so take what I say with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @NoviceMe Short answer: Yes, Google's in-app billing is the _same_ as Text2Pay (from a user point of view).

Comment: thanks for your reply. But see this app is for indian audience. using credit card to pay for app there is very difficult. 90% of the time it does not work. so i liked text2pay becauce it charges your sim. do you know if google has something similar?

Comment: @NoviceMe You should have mentioned Text2Pay in your original question - but in any case no, Google does not have anything similar as far as I'm know.